# How can we set maximum string length dynamically?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I am using a database field for input textbox. I want to allow the maximum limit of this textbox entry to be equivalent to the size of the database column. I can hard code it based on the column length but I want to set a dynamic value so that if the length of the column changes, the maximum limit of the textbox should change automatically.

Comment: PrimeFaces input has length and size attribute. Check the documentation. What is 'wrong' with just using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
<p:inputText maxlength="#{yourBeanName.propertyYouSetWithLengthFromDB}"></p:inputText>
```

Just don't forget to initialize variable with some initial value :)